# Write a simple looping program

Tags: python

I want to write a program with this logic.

```
A value is presented of the user.
Commence a loop
    Wait for user input
    If the user enters the displayed value less 13 then
       Display the value entered by the user and go to top of loop.
    Otherwise exit the loop
```

Comment: So you want a program that lets the user answer what 2363 or `a` minus `b` which is always 13? And if it's the wrong answer it keeps asking the user till it's right. And if it's right it updates a to be `a-13`? So `2363 -13 = 2350` and then next loop it asks what `2350 -13` is ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need two `while` loops. One that keeps the main program going forever, and another that breaks and resets the value of `a` once an answer is wrong.

```
while True:
    a = 2363
    not_wrong = True

    while not_wrong:
        their_response = int(raw_input("What is the value of {} - 13?".format(a)))
        if their_response == (a - 13):
            a = a -13
        else:
            not_wrong = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you're supposed to show your attempt at coding towards a solution and posting when you encounter a problem, you could do something like the following:

```
a = 2363
b = 13
while True:
    try:
        c = int(input('Subtract {0} from {1}: '.format(b, a))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer.')
        continue

    if a-b == c:
        a = a-b
    else:
        print('Incorrect. Restarting...')
        a = 2363
        # break
```

(use `raw_input` instead of `input` if you're using Python2)

This creates an infinite loop that will try to convert the input into an integer (or print a statement pleading for the correct input type), and then use logic to check if `a-b == c`. If so, we set the value of `a` to this new value `a-b`. Otherwise, we restart the loop. You can uncomment the `break` command if you don't want an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, might want to look into `while loop`, and `input`. While loops keeps going until a condition is met:

```
while (condition):
    # will keep doing something here until condition is met
```

Example of while loop:

```
x = 10
while x >= 0:
    x -= 1
    print(x)
```

This will print x until it hits 0 so the output would be 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 in new lines on console.

`input` allows the user to enter stuff from console:

```
x = input("Enter your answer: ")
```

This will prompt the user to "Enter your answer: " and store what ever value user enter into the variable x. (Variable meaning like a container or a box)

Put it all together and you get something like:

```
a = 2363              #change to what you want to start with
b = 13                #change to minus from a

while a-b > 0:        #keeps going until if a-b is a negative number
    print("%d - %d = ?" %(a, b))                      #asks the question
    user_input = int(input("Enter your answer: "))    #gets a user input and change it from string type to int type so we can compare it
    if (a-b) == user_input:         #compares the answer to our answer
        print("Correct answer!") 
        a -= b                      #changes a to be new value
    else:
        print("Wrong answer") 

print("All done!")
```

Now this program stops at `a = 7` because I don't know if you wanted to keep going with negative number. If you do just edited the condition of the while loop. I'm sure you can manage that.